# Can Spring BeanPostProcessor initialize the bean which defined in Configuration

Tags: spring

I add the bean definition of some configuration into the registry in `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry`, and there are several beans defined in the configuration class file.

```
public class MySettingConfigImpl implements MySettingConfig {

    @Bean
    MyMailmigrationSetting myMailmigrationSetting() {
        return new MyMailmigrationSetting(true, 10);
    }
}
```

After `refresh()`, I thought the bean of `MyMailmigrationSetting` should be created, But in fact it didn't. When I try to get the bean, it will throw BeanNotFound exception.

I just want to know:

1. Does the `BeanPostProcessor` could help to generate the beans which
   defined in the configuration class.
2. If not, then how can I generate
   the bean which defined in the configuration programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried using Spring `@Configuration` in your class ?

Comment: Yes, I add `@GuardedConfiguration` for the configuration class.

Comment: use Spring @Configuration from (org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration) and check